# Android SmsManager.sendTextMessage fails without error

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I am trying to send an SMS from the application Activity. Issue is that there is no exception thrown, and I can see that SMS is shown in my sent items (when I open SMS message app) but with small red icon with label "Failed".

I have permission added to the application manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

As well as I do explicitly ask for permission when activity starts.

```java
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("App requires send sms permission");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS }, 1);
        return;
}
```

When I send SMS, code is:

```java
try {
        System.out.println("Sending sms...");
        SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(2);
        smgr.sendTextMessage("a valid recipient phone num",null,"Test 123",null,null);
        System.out.println("SMS sent.");
}
catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I call getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(2) instead of getDefault() because I have 2 SIM cards device and ID is correctly set to 2.

Recipient phone number is in international format (starts with +, then country code etc).

I can see in console output "SMS sent" and no error thrown, however, when I go to SMS app and check outbox, I see the message "Test 123" is in there, with correct recipient phone number, but has small red icon next to it with label "Failed". It also has marked correct [2] for SIM card.

I can tap on that icon manually and resend it, in which case it works.

Also tried using `getDefault` for SMS manager, which then selects SIM card #1, but fails the same.

When running app for the first time it does prompt to allow permission to send SMS which I opt-in "Allow".

Also important: failed SMS does not immediately appear in my sent items, rather after 5-10 minutes.

Anyone had same issue? I'm lost now, have no idea where more to look at.

P.S. Edited above code to set `null` for service center number, as suggested by Mike.M. in the comments. Still the same issue though.

From logcat:

```
2020-08-31 20:40:36.910 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Debug: Trying to get all SIM cards available...
2020-08-31 20:40:36.913 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Subscription ID: 1
2020-08-31 20:40:36.913 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Subscription ID: 2
2020-08-31 20:40:37.849 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Handle a message...
2020-08-31 20:40:37.849 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Process queue...
2020-08-31 20:40:37.859 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Query update user done!
2020-08-31 20:40:37.859 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Data saved.
2020-08-31 20:40:38.859 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Handle a message...
2020-08-31 20:40:38.859 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Process queue...
2020-08-31 20:40:38.864 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Query update user done!
2020-08-31 20:40:38.864 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Data saved.
2020-08-31 20:40:39.865 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Handle a message...
2020-08-31 20:40:39.865 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Process queue...
2020-08-31 20:40:39.870 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Query update user done!
2020-08-31 20:40:39.870 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Data saved.
2020-08-31 20:40:40.870 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Handle a message...
2020-08-31 20:40:40.870 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Process queue...
2020-08-31 20:40:40.876 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Query update user done!
2020-08-31 20:40:40.876 10587-10630/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Data saved.
2020-08-31 20:40:56.502 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:2096808189
2020-08-31 20:40:56.518 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@b397f90
2020-08-31 20:40:56.552 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Sending sms...
2020-08-31 20:40:56.552 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Subscription ID of current sms-manager: 2
2020-08-31 20:40:56.552 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: Sending SMS to number: +[my phone number, removed from this report]
2020-08-31 20:40:56.552 10587-10587/com.miradjajic.distancecare I/System.out: SMS sent.
```

No exceptions thrown.

Comment: The second parameter in `sendTextMessage()` is _not_ for the sender's number. It's for a service center. Unless you have already somehow determined what the appropriate service center numbers are, leave it `null`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you for this information! I've updated it to null, alas, still the same result.

Comment: please attach the stacktrace with the question.

Comment: @Ali all I have in logcat is just "Sending sms..." followed by "SMS sent".  There is no error thrown or any warning.

Comment: For what is worth: above code works on a phone that has 1 SIM card, just tested and SMS is successfully sent. Still fails on my 2-SIM card phone (Xiaomi Mi8 Pro)